# How to edit clip path?

Tags: vector, inkscape, mask, windows

The [Inkscape FAQ](http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/inkscape-faq-how-do-i-crop-in-inkscape/) states:

> In fact, if you use a path as the clipping object, you can actually edit the clip path without having to Release it. First select the clipped object, then choose the Node Editing Tool. Your clip path will be outlined Green, with the normal path editing nodes visible.

Well, I have clipped a bitmap with a path. Yet, when I select the clipped object with the tool *"Edit paths by nodes (F2)"*, then I get no path editing nodes. There is just a dotted outline around the object.

I am using Inkscape 0.48.5 on Windows 7 x64.

*Am I doing something wrong? Is my version of Inkscape not capable of doing that? Something else?*

[image: Screenshot illustrating the issue]

Comment: Jesus, what resolution _is_ that?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* do  this, but you have to enable "Show clipping path(s) of selected object(s)"

[image: Imgur]

For smaller screens :

[image: Imgur]

Also, when you move the image, the clip path doesn't move with the image, so things like this can happen:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: That's it! At least in v0.91pre1_64bit, I cannot reproduce the image-move-problem, fortunately.

Comment: I'm using 0.92.1 on Kubuntu but I don't see that setting. Instead I have a global setting (which was enabled) that says to delete the clipping object when the clip is set. Unsetting doesn't show me the object even, and there's definitely no green path either.