# Edit clip path nodes not showing up on Windows

Tags: vector, inkscape, windows

I am running Inkscape 0.92 on Windows 10.

I have clipped a portion out of a picture and "Show clipping path(s) of selected object(s)" is also enabled as per this [similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36545/how-to-edit-clip-path). However I do not see any nodes to edit the clip path. Below is my screenshot. As can be seen, no nodes are visible to edit the clip path. Am I hitting some bug? I saw the same behaviour on my Ubuntu 18 machine running same version of Inkscape.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that the image shown represents a vector graphic or a raster graphic. If the latter, there are no nodes to a raster image.

Answer (score 2):

Your clipping path seem to be a circle. It's not a path altough it can be used for clipping. The reason isn't the clipped object is a photo.

Release the clip, select the circle, goto Path > Object to path (=convert the circle to bezier curve). Set the clip again. Now the clipping path is editable with the node tool if the option for it is on (=show clipping path for selected object).

To be exact also the circle should be editable. But there's a bug somewhere. The editing handles of the circle can be somewhere far away from the circle.

Answer (score 2):

If the clipping object is a Circle object and not a path, then nodes and handles won't show up. What you will have instead are some Circle controls which are usually placed at the top of the page. You may have to zoom out to find them.

For example:

[image]

Note: if you want to scale the circle proportionally, you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag one of the little squares. The circular shaped control is to create arc segments.